# Insufficient privileges registering xml schema in database

Tags: oracle, xsd

using this instruction :
    DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.REGISTERSCHEMA(filenamer,clobFile);

I have the following errors

```
ORA-31084: error while creating table "USER"."Document1592_TAB" for element "Document"
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XMLSCHEMA_INT", line 72
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XMLSCHEMA", line 33
```

Of course this user can create tables, do you know where it could come from ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't have privileges to `create,alter,drop,...` types.

Also you can try to register xsd without creating any objects

```
DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.REGISTERSCHEMA(
    schemaurl       => filenamer
    schemadoc       => clobFile
    gentypes         => FALSE
    gentables        => FALSE
);
```

Comment: With this user I can create and drop types

Comment: What about `under` and 'execute' privileges? Moreover for testing purpose you can grant to you user(crete/under/alter/execute/drop) any types